# Conda environment creation in HPC

Tags: bash, conda, bioinformatics, hpc

I've just been provided an HPC user and want to create my environments. However, when i try to create them, i get this message:

```
(base) [xxxxx@front ~]$ conda create -n rnaseq -c bioconda -f rnaseq.yml
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for channel admin <https://conda.anaconda.org/admin>

The channel is not accessible or is invalid.

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

Using `conda config --show-sources` gives the following:

```
(base) [xxxxx@front ~]$ conda config --show-sources
==> /opt/conda/.condarc <==
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org/
channels:
  - admin

==> /xxxxx/.condarc <==
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org/
channels:
  - admin
```

When I check the conda info i see there is no conda-build installed, could it be related to the problem? Or is it that admin does not allow me to create environments?

Conda info:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /opt/conda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /xxxxx/.condarc
 populated config files : /opt/conda/.condarc
                          /xxxxx/.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.34=0
                          __linux=5.15.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /opt/conda  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /opt/conda/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/admin/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/admin/noarch
          package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs
                          /xxxxx/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/conda/envs
                          /xxxxx/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.10.4 Linux/5.15.0-102.110.5.1.el9uek.x86_64 ol/9.2 glibc/2.34
                UID:GID : 10063:100000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I tried to create a conda environment in an HPC, expected for the environment to be created but conda shows that admin channel is not accessible.

Conda - version 23.1.0
OS - Oracle Linux

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to the sysadmin(s). That `admin` appears intentional, so they should be able to give an explanation. E.g., they might be trying to provide a curated local channel, but maybe something is misconfigured. `conda-build` is not the issue.

As a workaround, one can ignore channels from `.condarc` files by using the `--override-channels` flag. Alternatively, in your YAML, you can add a `nodefaults` "channel" to ignore channels found in configurations.

Also, be aware that `-c bioconda` is invalid - it must always be `-c conda-forge -c bioconda`.